# how to find the totalamount of hot metal filled in?

Tags: random

I have a truck carrying hot metal. There is always some unknown amount of residual hot metal inside this truck. At start of day i fill it up with some amount of hot metal. I take this truck to weigh bridge and weigh it. Then i take it to the consumer and give him some hot metal. After that then I again weigh the truck. this continues say 4 times in a day. the weighing details are given below:

a)688.05 T(Tonnes) (while going to customer) , 365.05 T(Tonnes)(after giving it customer)
b)606.40 T , 300.70 T
c)619.35 T, 310.35  T
d)595.35 T, 306.35 T
-what is the total amount of hot metal i have filled inside the truck in one day considering some unknown amount of hot metal will always be residing inside the truck at any moment of time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you have some thoughts about the problem? What have you tried? Perhaps the difference between "after" and "while going .." is important?